# boost log locks on exit

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I have the following (stripped down) logger code that works as expected except when the application exists in a specific scenario.
When the logger seems to be writing the log file and the application exists, the logger locks and the application does not exit.
Here is the logger code sample and the main that works with it that can reproduce the problem:

```
#include <boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/drop_on_overflow.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/bounded_fifo_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/clock.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/current_process_name.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/current_process_id.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/current_thread_id.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>

namespace blog = boost::log;

constexpr uint32_t LOG_QUEUE_BOUND_LINES = 10000;
constexpr uint32_t MAX_FILE_SIZE_FOR_ROTATION_MB = (10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10MB
constexpr uint32_t MAX_TIME_FOR_ROTATION_IN_HOURS = (24 * 7); // 1 week

using LogAsyncSink = boost::log::sinks::asynchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend,
    boost::log::sinks::bounded_fifo_queue<
    LOG_QUEUE_BOUND_LINES_NUM,
    boost::log::sinks::drop_on_overflow>>;

boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> _logger;

boost::shared_ptr<LogAsyncSink> fileGlobalSink;

#define LOG_FORMAT blog::expressions::stream \
    << blog::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") \
    << " [" \
    << blog::expressions::attr<blog::trivial::severity_level>("Severity") \
    << "] " \
    << blog::expressions::attr<std::string>("Process") \
    << ":" \
    << blog::expressions::attr<blog::process_id>("ProcessID") \
    << ":" \
    << blog::expressions::attr<blog::thread_id>("ThreadID") \
    << " " \
    << blog::expressions::message

boost::shared_ptr<LogAsyncSink> AddFile(const std::string& fileName)
{
    // No need to guard since this can be called only from functions that are guarded
    boost::shared_ptr<LogAsyncSink> returnSink(nullptr);
    boost::shared_ptr<blog::sinks::text_file_backend> textFile =
        boost::make_shared<blog::sinks::text_file_backend>(blog::keywords::file_name = fileName);

    textFile->set_file_name_pattern(fileName);

    // set rolling mechanism
    textFile->set_rotation_size(MAX_FILE_SIZE_FOR_ROTATION_MB);
    textFile->set_time_based_rotation(
        blog::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_interval(boost::posix_time::hours(MAX_TIME_FOR_ROTATION_IN_HOURS)));

    boost::shared_ptr<LogAsyncSink> fileSink(new LogAsyncSink(textFile));
    fileSink->set_formatter(
        LOG_FORMAT
    );
    fileSink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);

    returnSink = fileSink;
    return returnSink;
}

void LoggerInit()
{
    std::string fileName = "logfilename.txt";
    boost::shared_ptr<LogAsyncSink> fileAdded;

    fileAdded = AddFile(fileName);
    auto core = blog::core::get();
    if (core != nullptr)
    {
        core->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", blog::attributes::local_clock());
        core->add_global_attribute("Process", blog::attributes::current_process_name());
        core->add_global_attribute("ProcessID", blog::attributes::current_process_id());
        core->add_global_attribute("ThreadID", blog::attributes::current_thread_id());

        core->add_sink(fileAdded);
        fileGlobalSink = fileAdded;
    }
}

void StopLogging()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<blog::core> core = blog::core::get();

    if (fileGlobalSink != nullptr)
    {
        if (core != nullptr)
        {
            // Remove the sink from the core, so that no records are passed to it
            core->remove_sink(fileGlobalSink);
        }

        // Flush all log records that may have left buffered
        fileGlobalSink->flush();

        // Break the feeding loop
        fileGlobalSink->stop();

        fileGlobalSink.reset();
    }
}

/******************************* main ****************************************/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    LoggerInit();
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(_logger, boost::log::trivial::trace) << "Test";
//    Sleep(10); -> Min exists correctly no lock
//    StopLogging(); -> everything closes correctly
}
```

As you can see if I add the sleep, the logger finish logging and exists correctly, if I add the call to `StopLogging()` then the logger close everything correctly and the application end correctly.
With out those two function the boost locks at:
async_frontend.cpp in the `stop()` function:

```
                while (m_StopRequested.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
                    m_BlockCond.wait(lock);
```

Any idea how to solve this? Am I doing something wrong in the logger definitions?

Comment: Is it an option to go without the globals? It does appear you're simply racing to shutdown before the backend started the "stop request" monitoring loop.

Comment: Theoretically, thats not "my problem" that the monitoring look did not start. if that is the case then it is a boost error. it should somehow verify the application is not in a shutdown action. I'm doing a valid action, creating a global variable and exiting from the application. Of course I can find a work around (as shown by the two commented lines). just wanted to validate two things. 1: That my core logger code is right. 2: That it might be a boost error.

Comment: How much of your `StopLogging` function is really needed? I know that the `asynchronous_sink` destructor at least "stops". It's kind of likely that it will be flushed as well.

Comment: @gilady If you understand your problem you can plot a path to solution (e.g. file a bug at Boost Log).

Comment: the StopLogging function is the safest way in case I want to close the sink without relaying on the destructor (and facing issues like the one I encountered).
I filed a bug at Boost log and they think it is a compiler issue.